# How to declare a queried value and use it in CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to convert the DOB into the number age, then assign the age value into different age groups on SQL Server.

I have found the way to do the first step, and the second step ideally I should set the first step's result as a variable and let it compare in the CASE statement. However, I don't know declare and set the variable and use it in CASE.

I got the table I want with a silly way as below:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
    CAST(
        CASE
            WHEN FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) < 18
                THEN 'Under 18'
            WHEN FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) BETWEEN 19 AND 30
                THEN '19-30'
            WHEN FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) > 30
                THEN 'Over 30'
            ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Age
FROM Student
```

**MY QUESTION:** Is there a way to set "FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(DOB AS INTEGER)) / 365.25)" as a variable and use it in the CASE statement?

*FirstName, LastName and dbo are columns in Student Table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in the `case` statement.  The two traditional recommendations are to use CTEs or subqueries.  But, SQL Server also supports `apply`:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
       (CASE WHEN v.age <= 18 THEN 'Under 18'
             WHEN v.age <= 30 THEN '19-30'
             WHEN v.age > 30 THEN 'Over 30'
             ELSE 'ERROR'
        END) AS Age
FROM Student s OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) )
     ) as v(age);
```

Comments:

- You don't need to cast strings to `varchar(10)`.  That is just superfluous.
- The `case` is evaluated in order, so you don't need `between`.  This makes it much easier if you want to change the boundaries.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon!